# Magento 2 API: Possible to edit an order?

Tags: magento2, orders, api, sales-order

I would like to know whether it is possible to **edit an order via API** analog to the functionality in the Magento 2 backend.

[image: Edit functionality in backend:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box it's not possible as you can see from this file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/webapi.xml

The only modifications you can do to an order via API are:

- cancel
- send the email
- hold
- unhold
- comment
- create (which is not really an edition)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I'm using the API incorrectly. But I'm using this function for editing an order:

```
PUT V1/orders/create
```

I know there is this "create" but also it's a PUT...

I'm using this because actually there is a issue on Magento that not change the status of the order when you do an invoice or shipping through API. More info here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3307